# Flag in ifort for avoiding passing inconsistent data types to a Fortran subroutine

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I am working on a 3rd party code in Fortran 90, this code used to work fine. Then there has been a recent update on the cluster that I work on, I am not sure about the details (I think the compiler stayed the same), then this 3rd party code has stopped working. Reading the code I have seen that some integer values, like 1 and -1 are passed to subroutines without a variable. Example:

```
integer, parameter :: sp = selected_int_kind(18)

subroutine sub(var)

integer(kind=sp), intent(in):: var

<do something>

return
end subroutine
```

and later in the main file:

```
call sub(1)
```

Examining the variables with `gdb` I have seen that inside `sub` `var` is not 1, but some large integer. This is due to inconsistent integer types.

I know how to solve this problem, that happens with `ifort 18.0.2`.

I have two questions:

- why this problem happens now after cluster update?
- is there a flag in the ifort compiler that can return an error or warning on passing inconsistent types?

Comment: You really need tho provide rhe actual code See [mcve].

Comment: Additionally, how are you compiling this code? If I try to compile your subroutine and `call sub(1)` using `gfortran 7.4.0`, it gives the compiler error `Type mismatch in argument 'var'; passed INTEGER(4) to INTEGER(8)`.

Comment: @veryreverie ifort 18.0.2

Comment: @simona ifort seems to (erroneously) accept the code you have given. You can replace the calls `call sub(1)` with `call sub(1_sp)`. If this doesn't solve the problem then we'll need a mwe as per @VladimirF's comment.

Comment: @veryreverie I had already solved the problem before posting the question. My question is why this happens, it did not happen before,there has been an update on the cluster, I am not entirely sure what the sysadmin updated. I was wondering if there is a flag in the ifort to avoid this behavior

Comment: Even asking if there is an ifort flag, we need to see a full example so we know what particular case you are asking about. There are several potential ifort options to help with debugging broken code.

Answer (score 3):

There is an ifort flag that can help - `-warn interface`. If this is enabled, the compiler will create an interface block for external procedures not in a module (classic F77 style). Then, when a call to a procedure is made, where there is no explicit interface, the compiler will look to see if there is a generated interface and compare them, giving you a warning if they don't match. It is not perfect - it depends on the called routine being compiled first.

As to why it happened, it all depends on what happens to be in memory following the argument passed.

The best solution is to have an explicit interface for all procedures. The current version supports Fortran 2018's `IMPLICIT NONE(EXTERNAL)`, which forces you to have an explicit interface (or EXTERNAL declaration) for all procedures you call. There is also a compile option to turn this on, `-warn externals`, but neither is in version 18.